# Can I use authorization via CanCan in a form input collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, cancan, simple-form, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to figure out how to limit the `:collection` of users to those who `can? :manage, @article.website`. As mentioned I'm using Cancan and I feel like I should be able to do something like this:

```
= f.input :user_id, collection: User.all unless cannot? :manage, @article.website
```

I'm using simple_form_for hence the f.input. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CanCan is designed to answer the question "can user U do X?".  I do not think cancan is designed to efficiently answer the question "which users can do X?".  You could theoretically do something like:

```
User.all.select { |u| Ability.new(u).can?(:manage, @article.website) }
```

but it would be horrendously inefficient.

Unless you have a very small number of users, you'd probably be better off handling this outside of cancan.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be done in the views - probably a view helper would be best for this case, but you should just have a condition that returns the collection that specific person can see.

```
module SomethingHelper

  def something_user_ids(article)
    if can? :manage, article.website
      User.all
    else
      User.where(guest: true) # or whatever
    end
  end

end
```

then in your view you would just do something like..

```
= f.input :user_id, collection: something_user_ids(@article)
```